In some surnames, is there a full stop and/or a space? eg McNally, St Cloud
eg McNally,should it be Mc.Nally? Mc Nally? Or Mc. Nally?
For StCloud is it including a full stop eg St.Cloud? Or with a space; St Cloud?
Is there a rule?
Thank you.

For Mac/Mc names, definitely no full stop or space.

If someone's name is "St Cloud", "St Clair", etc, you have a choice of copying how they do it, or if in doubt, do it as you would any other saint or thing named after a saint; you may or may not use a period.

@KateBunting Mac is often written followed by a space in Celtic names used in Ireland and Scotland; but never with a full stop. Copy how the person writes it.

@StuartF, thanks. So there's no fixed rule for a right or wrong way as far as you're aware?

Mac/Mc is not considered an abbreviation, so there's no need for the period. But "St" is an abbreviation for "Saint", so it usually gets a period.

@Barmar in BrE, if the first and last letters are there, no stop is used. So in BrE we have Mr Dr St etc. without any stop (period in AmE). Whereas etc. has the stop, even it if is often omitted.

For people who have a last name such as "St. John," I wonder if they usually consider their last name to technically be "Saint John" and they usually abbreviate their last name when they're writing it, or if they consider the abbreviated form itself to be their last name.
